# Can AppleScript be able to click the menu extra of a 3rd-party app?

Tags: applescript, menu-bar, parallels-desktop

Many 3rd-party apps have small menu icons at the top-right corner of the menu bar such as Evernote, iStat, Parallels Desktop and so on.
I tried to write some AppleScripts to **click those menu icons, but all failed**.

Take "PD" for example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Parallels Desktop"
        get properties of every menu bar item of every menu bar
    end tell
end tell
```

I can get multiple menu items such as "Apple", "Parallels Desktop", "File", "Edit", ..., "Help", which are apparently the top-left menus of PD. 
Besides, **a menu extra** is also obtained and is described as follows:

*{minimum value:missing value, orientation:missing value, position:{1338, 0}, class:menu bar item, accessibility description:"", role description:"menu extra", focused:false, title:missing value, size:{30, 22}, help:"", entire contents:{}, enabled:true, maximum value:missing value, role:"AXMenuBarItem", value:missing value, subrole:"AXMenuExtra", selected:false, name:missing value, description:""}*

After verifying the position by Accessibility Inspector, I can confirm that this menu extra is the menu icon I want to click. Then I write this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Parallels Desktop"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end tell
```

or replace the "click" statement with:

```
perform action "AXPress" of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
```

or with:

```
perform action "AXShowMenu" of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
```

All of the above codes return the same result: *missing value*, and no menus show up at all!

As for the System UI Elements such as "input text", "date and time", "wifi", "battery", "VPN", the click method works. BUT for 3rd-party apps, it doesn't work.

So, how to click those 3rd-party menu extras via AppleScript?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I found that some 3rd party apps -especially ones that have a custom drop down menu- seem not to be scriptable. I heard of a trick to use Automator and its "Menu Workflow > Record [Shift-Cmd-R]" watch-me-do menu item that returns some "action icons" that can next be pasted in ScriptEditor. I succeeded in recording some clicks onto Avira's menu icon that could be "repeated" from Automator – but would NOT "replay" if pasted identically into a ScriptEditor window. At least you can get an exact description of your "menu icon" through this procedure, or maybe use an Automator app in the end ....

Answer (score 2):

I was having an issue getting AppleScript to click on the menu extra of iTeleport Connect until I tried the following:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTeleport Connect"
tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2)
    click --  This click appears to be the important addition that allows you to drill down to the other items
    click menu item "Connect" of menu 1
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: The OP clearly already tried this and stated it did not work.

Comment: The addition of the lone "click" makes it work. :-)

Comment: Doesn't matter that you wrote it differently as both execute the event as `tell application "System Events" to click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of process "ProcessName"`!